# Scala Try/Catch block in Scala fails to catch Exception

Tags: scala, exception

In the code below, when a ConnectException is thrown by the first line inside the try block, it is not caught. I am rethrowing the exception as the original exception message, "Connection Refused", is not useful for debugging, so I am adding some more information. However, my exception with the "Failed to connect..." message is never displayed. I only ever see the original "Connection Refused" exception message.

```
private[this] def getClient(system: ActorSystem, config: Config): ConfigException Xor Conn =
  for {
    natsConfig <- config.configAt("messaging.nats")
    userName   <- natsConfig.readString("user")
    password   <- natsConfig.readString("password")
    host       <- natsConfig.readString("host")
    port       <- natsConfig.readString("port")
  } yield {
    val props = new Properties()
    props.put("servers", "nats://" + userName + ":" + password + "@" + host + ":" + port)
    log.debug("NATS connection properties:" + props.getProperty("servers"))
    try {
      val client = Conn.connect(props)
      system.registerOnTermination {
        client.close()
      }
      client
    } catch {
      case ex:ConnectException =>
        throw new ConnectException("Failed to connect to nats using props:" + props.getProperty("servers"))
    }
  }
```

The output I get is:

> I|16:25:15.561|o.g.s.messaging.MessageBusManager$|Starting NATS
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>       at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
>       at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:454)
>       at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:446)
>       at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648)
>       at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:189)
>       at org.nats.Connection.connect(Connection.java:211)
>       at org.nats.Connection.(Connection.java:164)
>       at org.nats.Conn.(Conn.scala:5)
>       at org.nats.Conn$.connect(Conn.scala:68)
>       at org.genivi.sota.messaging.nats.NatsClient$$anonfun$getClient$1$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(NatsClient.scala:30)

Note the exception message, which does not match the one in the catch block. NatsClient:30 is the first line of the catch block

The code above is trying to connect to a NATS messaging server using scala_nats. Even if I change the catch case to Throwable, the exception is still not caught. However, if I throw a ConnectException in the first line of the try, that exception is caught. I have also tried adding *root* to my imports to ensure there is no namespace conflicts, to no avail.

Under what circumstances can Scala fail to catch exceptions here?

Comment: How do you determine that it is not caught?

Comment: The original ConnectException has a message of "Connection Refused". The exception I thrown has another string, however I only see "Connection Refused" in the logs.

Comment: Perhaps, it is logged before you catch it?

Comment: So logging can bypass try/catch?

Comment: no, logging cannot bypass anything.  But if the exception gets logged _before_ you catch it, then catching it later cannot have any effect on it getting logged.

Comment: In this case, the output is from stdout/stderr, so I doubt it getting logged before catching is an issue here.

Comment: It makes no difference _where_ it is logged. Only _when_. I mean, the fact that you see it in stdout is inconsequential. You should accept the fact that basic language constructs like `try/catch`, probably do work as advertised, and focus on looking for other, more plausible explanations.

Comment: Agreed, I doubt try/catch is broken. However, I don't understand how an exception can bubble up and be printed to stdout/stderr, before it is caught by an enclosing catch block. Can you link to an example?

Comment: There could be more than one try/catch block ...

Comment: You mean something along the lines of another try catch block around the one I have, which simply throws a ConnectException with the message "Connection Refused"? That is the only possible scenario I can think of.

Comment: Are you importing the correct ConnectException ?

Comment: Yes, I am using java.net.ConnectException, and I have also tried prepending "_root_" to eliminate any namespace conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant code snippet of [Connection.java](https://github.com/tyagihas/java_nats/blob/5a119ea30ab56a5e71c0ad94bb1e15df42739cb7/src/main/java/org/nats/Connection.java) in the Java_Nats library:

```
private boolean connect() throws IOException {
    try {
        InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(servers[current].host, servers[current].port);
        channel = SocketChannel.open(addr);
        while(!channel.isConnected()){}         
        servers[current].connected = true;
    } catch(Exception ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

According to your stack trace, `SocketChannel.open()` fails. Then the exception is caught, logged and swallowed so it will not reach your handler.

N.b. the code above is from version 0.5.1 of the library. The latest (0.6.0) one is updated and would throw an IOException, no logging.

---

(My original answer was completely off:)

> The exception is caught but you immediately throw another one. I think
>   you intend to return (not throw) the exception object as a `Xor.left`
>   instead. (At least this is what the declared return type
>   `ConfigException Xor Conn` suggests.)

Comment: I wasn't clear. I am rethrowing the exception with more information added to aid debugging. The issue is that the catch block is never executed.

Comment: I am indeed using 0.5.1. Thanks for the great answer, especially given my unclear question.

Answer (score 1):

The `ConnectException` is being caught on this line:

```
} catch {
  case ex:ConnectException => println("HELLO!!!")
```

But you're immediately throwing another `ConnectException`.

Generally speaking you shouldn't wrap an exception with another exception.

From what I see here, don't use a try block at all!

Comment: Yes, however in this case, I am adding more information to the exception before rethrowing it. But the exception is never rethrown.

Comment: To be precise, you are creating a *new* exception instance with perhaps better information, and you throw that. You do not *re*throw the caught one.